# Webpack не ребилдит файл при изменениях

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack2

1. есть простой (там только один `console.log`) скрипт `script.js`, который я упаковываю вебпаком в модуль и записывают в `main.bundle.js`.
2. если поменять содержимое `script.js`, и запустить комманду `webpack` то модуль билдится с новым кодом.
3. если поменять содержимое `script.js`, и запустить комманду `webpack-dev-server` модуль тоже билдится с новым кодом. **НО!** Когда я вношу изменения в исходный файл илю удаляю скомпилированный, изменения не применяются и новый файл не создается, даже не смотря на то, что в консоль пишет:

   ```
   webpack: Compiling...
   Hash: 30798a2a1b23da35b30a
   Version: webpack 2.4.1
   Time: 40ms
            Asset    Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
   main.bundle.js  317 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
   chunk    {0} main.bundle.js (main) 303 kB [entry] [rendered]
      [35] ./client/dev/script.js 17 bytes {0} [built]
        + 86 hidden modules
   webpack: Compiled successfully.
   ```

вот мой `webpack.config.js`:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './client/dev/script.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './client/public/js/'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        hot: true,
        contentBase: "./client/public/",
        port: 6611,
    }
};
```

версии модулей:

- "webpack": "2.4.1",
- "webpack-dev-server": "2.4.2"

**Вопрос:** Чего ему не хватает? Почему не происходит ребилд при изменении содержимого файла?

Answer (score 0):

Добавь в свой `webpack.config.js` опцию `watch: true`
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/#components/sidebar/sidebar.jsx